# Free Space in Table

Tags: oracle, free, space

we have a table with over 500,000,000 row in it.   So, did some maintenance and moved some of those records elsewhere.    What I'm curious about is how much space is available in that table now that more than 1/2 of the rows have been deleted.   When I look in the dictionary, it still shows 18GB, of which there must be a lot of room unallocated now.

I tried running DBMS_SPACE:

```
VARIABLE total_blocks NUMBER
VARIABLE total_bytes NUMBER
VARIABLE unused_blocks NUMBER
VARIABLE unused_bytes NUMBER
VARIABLE lastextf NUMBER
VARIABLE last_extb NUMBER
VARIABLE lastusedblock NUMBER
exec DBMS_SPACE.UNUSED_SPACE('CUSTOMER', 'LOGIN_LOG', 'TABLE', :total_blocks, :total_bytes,:unused_blocks, :unused_bytes, :lastextf, :last_extb, :lastusedblock);
```

However, the FREE_SPACE item is NULL:

```
SQL> print
  FREE_BLOCKS
  -----------

  TOTAL_BLOCKS
  ------------
     2436608

  TOTAL_BYTES
  -----------
     1.9961E+10
```

So, just wondering if I am missing something, or there is a different way of doing this?

Comment: If you've deleted half the rows in each block, you won't see any change with that procedure I believe. There's another procedure in the same package that has finer details if applicable (ASSM only I think). Coarse measure is with up to date stats, compare avg_row_len * num_rows to num_blocks * block size.

Answer (score 0):

You have freed up space, but that space is still allocated (reserved) for *that* table. So as that table continues to grow, it will reuse that deleted space.

Hence the total size of the table remains unchanged - just that it is unlikely to grow any further until all of the deleted space get reused by new data.

If you are not expecting the table to get any more rows, then you can reorganise the table (shuffle the rows around) in order to reclaim that space back to the tablespace so that other objects can take advantage of it.

To do that you can do (depending your machine):

```
alter table T move online;
```

or

```
alter table T enable row movement;
alter table T shrink space;
```